# Jquery Mobile 1.4.5 filter listview with multiple select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, filter

Hello I am buillding a Jquery mobile 1.4.5 website based on jqm 1.4.5 and latest Jquery

I am trying to filter a list (html):

```
<div id="placeholder" class="ui-field-contain" data-role="fieldcontain">
 <ul data-inset="true" data-input="#filter" data-filter="true" data-role="listview">
 <li data-filtertext="1">
 <p>Some text</p>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

with a multiple popup select box list:

```
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-enhanced="true" data-mini="true" >
<select name="select-1" id="select-1" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
    <option>text</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" >2</option>
    <option value="3" >3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

The js i am trying is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$('#select-1').on('change', function (e){
var value = $('#select-1').val();
$("ul").find("li").hide()
$("ul").find("li."+value).show();
});
 </script>
```

However When I check boxes everything (both list and select boxes dissapear)

can someone help me or point me to the right direction?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your list an ID so you can target only its listitems.  By using the `$("UL")` selector you are hiding listitems in all ULs in the DOM, including the multiple select popup.

A multi-select box `.val()` returns an array of values, and `null` when nothing is selected. So first check for `null` and then show all listitems as no filter is active.

If `.val()` is not `null` then one or more filter items is/are selected. So go through each listitem, get its data-filtertext attribute and see if that attribute is in the array of selected filter items. Then show or hide each listitem accordingly:

```
$('#select-1').on('change', function (e){
    var filtvalue = $('#select-1').val();
    if (!filtvalue){
        //show all with no filter
        $("#theList").find("li").show();
    } else {
        $("#theList").find("li").each(function(idx){
            //get filter text
            var filtText = $(this).attr("data-filtertext");
            if ($.inArray(filtText, filtvalue) > -1){
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    }
 });
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/vj8mca36/1/)**

Comment: One quick post-question. For more multiselect boxes that will run simultaneously for the same list, the logic is the same? I will have to create more if() loops?

Comment: I made a new example based on @ezanker code,http://jsfiddle.net/vj8mca36/5/         but if someone wants the filters to run simultaneously how can it be accomplished?

Comment: @qwertyg, you should combine them into one handler that considers all filter criteria: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/vj8mca36/6/

Comment: yes but still the if shows both criterias met. For exmaple if we choose from filter 1 only the 1 checkbox and from filter 2 only the 2 checkbox, if the logic we want to accomplish is to run all criterias at the same time, then no list items should appear.

Comment: @qwertyg, just change the 'or (||)' to 'and (&&)' if that is the way you want it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/vj8mca36/8/

Comment: first of all sorry to occupy your time...I got what you did there, but this criteria is if we want both checkboxed selected in order to show one list item. What i am trying to do is, to filter the list items in parallel. so if 1 is checked in filter1 and 2 is checked in filter2, then nothing shows up correctly. but if only filter1 with checkbox1 is selected then, item 1 appears.  if both checkboxes1 from both filters are checked then, item1 appears. I dont know if it is clear.